# Extract string based on pattern in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list of strings and I would like to extract part of it.

For example:

- red/blue/yellow/nav/white-black-green/**white-black-green-start**/OpenApi03Metadata
- red/blue/yellow/nav/white-black-green/**white-black-green-start**/api3UpdateMetadata
- red/teal/yellow/nav/white-black-cyan/**white-black-cyan-start**/api3CreateMetadata

I want to extract only the bold part of the address. The number of characters in the string varies, so I am not sure how to go about this.

Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: The examples are useful, but it would help if you clarified the characteristics of the components you want to extract. "Contains three (or more) hyphens"? "Ends with 'start'"? "Starts with 'white' and ends with 'start' "? ...)

Answer (score 1):

With `gsub` and capture group (`\\1`)

```
gsub(".*(white-.*start).*", "\\1", stri)
[1] "white-black-green-start" "white-black-green-start"
[3] "white-black-cyan-start"
```

by position

```
sapply(strsplit(stri, "/"), "[", 6)
[1] "white-black-green-start" "white-black-green-start"
[3] "white-black-cyan-start"
```

##### Data

```
stri <- c("red/blue/yellow/nav/white-black-green/white-black-green-start/OpenApi03Metadata", 
"red/blue/yellow/nav/white-black-green/white-black-green-start/api3UpdateMetadata", 
"red/teal/yellow/nav/white-black-cyan/white-black-cyan-start/api3CreateMetadata"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this in base R, it's a lot easier with the `str_extract` function from the `stringr` library.  For example:

```
library(stringr)

mystr <- "red/blue/yellow/nav/white-black-green/white-black-green-start/OpenApi03Metadata"

str_extract(mystr, "white-[a-z]+-[a-z]+-start")
# "white-black-green-start"
```

This also works on vectors of strings, and will return a vector of substrings matching the regex pattern in the second argument.  Note that `str_extract` uses the string (or vector) as its first argument and the pattern as its second, in contrast to the usual syntax of "pattern first, then string" in base R functions like `grep`.